OpenAI API error: "You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0
I am currently working on a gpt content creator system, and as I am using Mac it does not let me migrate to newer OpenAI library or downgrade it. Could I replace the ChatCompletion function with something else to work on my version?
heres the code:
import os
import openai

# Set the API key from an environment variable
openai.api_key = os.environ.get("api key ")

# Prompt GPT for content generation
prompt = "Write a blog post introducing an automated marketing platform for small businesses."
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[
        {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
    ],
    max_tokens=500,
    temperature=0.7,
)

# Print the generated content
print(response.choices[0].message.content)

And this is the full error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbook/marketing-automation/gpt_content_generation.py", line 9, in <module>
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  File "/Users/macbook/marketing-automation/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai/lib/_old_api.py", line 39, in __call__
    raise APIRemovedInV1(symbol=self._symbol)
openai.lib._old_api.APIRemovedInV1: 

You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.

You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface. 

Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28`

A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

I tried both upgrading and downgrading through pip.

if you check link then you may see in documentation client = openai.OpenAI(api_key=...) and response = client.chat.completions.create(message=..., model=...)

Does this answer your question? OpenAI API error: "You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0"

Code from openai/openai-python: The official Python library for the OpenAI API
    client = openai.OpenAI(
        api_key=os.environ.get(" api key ")
    )

    response = client.chat.completions.create(
        messages=[
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": prompt,
            }
        ],
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    )

